# UICollectionView vertical flow layout keep in collection bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with vertical cells alignment, but I want also vertical section alignment, I also want to keep the sections inside the current frame of the UICollectionView, that means if a section reach the end and it's longer then the collection itself, then it will go to next line.

This is how it looks right now:

[image: collectionview]

This is the final result I want to end up with:

[image: final collection]

This is my code so far:

```
class LettersCollectionTestViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionContainer: UIView!
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    private let ReuseIdentifierCollectionLetterCell = "LetterCollectionViewCell"

    var collectionWords: NSArray?

    var itemSize: CGFloat = 25.0
    var itemSpacing: CGFloat = 5.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let logoWord: String = "This is just this"
        self.collectionWords = logoWord.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        self.initializeCollection()
    }

    func initializeCollection() {

        let collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.itemSize, self.itemSize)
        collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = self.itemSpacing
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical

        let collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.collectionContainer.bounds, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
        collectionView.delegate = self;
        collectionView.dataSource = self;
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        collectionView.registerClass(LetterCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.ReuseIdentifierCollectionLetterCell)
        collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: self.ReuseIdentifierCollectionLetterCell, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.ReuseIdentifierCollectionLetterCell)

        self.collectionView = collectionView
        self.collectionContainer.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("clicked item at index: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: LetterCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.ReuseIdentifierCollectionLetterCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LetterCollectionViewCell

        let scalingTransform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
        cell.transform = scalingTransform

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (self.collectionWords?.objectAtIndex(section).length)!
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return (self.collectionWords?.count)!
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: self.itemSpacing, left: self.itemSpacing, bottom: self.itemSpacing, right: self.itemSpacing)
    }

}
```

What do I need to do? I know I should create a custom FlowLayout, but where should I start? I never did it before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need a custom UICollectionViewLayout to do this. Or at least a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout. The standard layout will not do what you want.

Comment: But how to start with this custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout, this is my first time trying to build this kind of thing..

Comment: There are some excellent tutorials on the Ray Wenderlich website about creating custom UIColelctionViewLayouts. I'd check those out first.

Comment: I've registered and bought an account in Ray Wenderlich, watched those videos all day long, but I think that what I'm trying to do is difficult.. I'll keep trying, eventually I'll learn that.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much.